# Prevent segmentation fault in buffer overflow demonstration in Ubuntu 12

Tags: c, security, bash, buffer-overflow

I am trying to run this piece of vulnerable C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
 int z =10;
 z = x + y;
 return z;
}

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int a = atoi(argv[1]);
 int b = atoi(argv[2]);
 int c;

 char buffer[100];

 gets(buffer);
 puts(buffer);

 c = add(a,b);

 printf("Sum of %d+%d = %d\n",a, b, c);

 exit(0);
}
```

I am trying to get past the segmentation fault so that I can input the integers but the segmentation fault prevents that. In the terminal I have tried:
 **gcc -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -Wa,--execstack -o SimpleDemo SimpleDemo.c**

I still get a segmentation fault. I am lost as to what to try next. As you can probably tell, I am an ubuntu newb. The bash code I am using comes from here:

http://www.evanjones.ca/buffer-overflow-101.html

I have been at this for while so would really appreciate some help

Cheers

Comment: You need to provide the integers as command-line arguments, not run the program and then enter them. If you don't, the `atoi(argv[1])` call will seg fault (probably).

Answer (score 1):

Just explaining what hmjd is asking you to do.

Run (binary) 10 20

Comment: Thanks guys. Just to clarify, when I run the program with - ./SimpleDemo, I put 10 and 20 on that line? How would the bash code to run this look?

Answer (score 0):

let me try to gues it run it with nothing but numbers:
myexec 1,2
myexec 1, 2
or , argv=2 ./myexec
and try in reverse order? c b a ??:
or however you figured it b,c,a order
so we have $anythingyouwant=indefinitething
this is A:
we have char *b  and stdin or stdout saying move the gets and puts to a function and call it using the call stack:
meaning you can set up your arg parameters --shadow-encountered:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).